# Using matched patterns in replace

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I don't see the [Sublime regex documentation](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/search_and_replace/search_and_replace_overview.html) saying anything about how to use matched patterns in the replace function. I tried to use the PHP/htaccess format of `$0` (and `$1` just in case the indexes start with 1), but no luck.

What I'm trying to do, is go through all my methods, and make static methods begin with an uppercase letter. So I would like to change all calls to `Foo::bar()` (PHP syntax) into `Foo::Bar()`. So even if I knew how to use the matched pattern (in this case `b`), is there a way to make it uppercase in the replace field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These operators are described in the [Boost regex library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/format/boost_format_syntax.html) reference:

> `\u`     Causes the next character to be outputted, to be output in upper case.

So, you may use `\u` uppercase operator in the replacement pattern to make the first character after it uppercase.

Search: `::(\w+\(\))`
Replace: `::\u$1`

[image]

Comment: Your search pattern doesn't really work completely correct. It matches `::logout` for example, but not `::redirect`.. I don't know if that's a bug or there's a good reason for that... But searching for `::([a-z])` and using your replace pattern worked well, so thank you :)

Comment: Since you said you have a working regex, I only suggested a sample pattern, to show that the `\u` works.